# Bar widths of flame graph in react profiler

Tags: reactjs

I was looking at react profiler which seems a really nice tool.
Have a look at these two screens:

[image]

and

[image]

What confuses me is following.
Look at the width of the `div` from first screenshot on which the left top corner of the tooltip starts (which says in total that component took 17.7 ms to render), now look at width of the `Row` on second screenshot (tooltip of which says in total that component took 12.9 ms to render). **Why is the width of `Row` larger than the width of `div` left to it?** When `div` in total took more time to render? According to the docs, should not it be other way around? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each bar in the flame graph needs to be wide enough to contain all of its children- even the ones that weren't even rendered in the current commit (the gray subtree starting with `TextField` in your screenshot above). that's why `Row` is wider than `div`. The *width* of each node gives you some idea of what the *overall cost* of that subtree would be if it were all to be rendered. In this case, and most cases, *color is the more important bit of information*.

[This note in the React Profiler docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html#flame-chart) mentions the distinction between color and width:

> The width of a bar indicates how long it took to render the component (and its children) *when they last rendered*. If the component did not re-render as part of this commit, the time represents a previous render. The wider a component is, the longer it took to render.
>
> The color of a bar indicates how long the component (and its children) took to render in the selected commit. Yellow components took more time, blue components took less time, and gray components did not render at all during this commit.

The key part of the note about is "when they last rendered".

Hope this helps clear up the confusion.

Comment: Thanks. Ah so you say it is wider because of its children that could have potentially been rendered? Hmm could be a bit confusing. The docs could have explained it a bit better don't you think?

Comment: Each bar hast to be wide enough to contain all of its children. Otherwise the flame graph would be a meaningless jumbled mess. If each bar has to contain every child, including children that didn't render (because they weren't updated / were memoized), then width alone can't be used to spot the most "expensive" thing in a given render/commit. That's why color is also useful.

Comment: I see. What I mean the docs could have explained it better. It could confuse other people too as it confused me. It says at places "The wider a component is, the longer it took to render." - then the reader must read between lines about the *last rendered* and somehow relate this with the width.